# Multiple routes from single page in NextJs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, prismic.io, next-router

I'm building a marketing/consumer site for my company, migrating away from WordPress (thank god) to a combo of Next and Prismic. Currently, our consumer site has about 600 pages to account for multiple product and landing pages for each of our 35+ dealers, but I'd like to move away from managing content for 600 pages, as all of the dealers share pages and content; the only thing that number of pages serves is allowing us to have enhanced SEO and url paths, so that each product page is a sub page of the dealers i.e. `san-diego-ca/product-page` `sacramento-ca/product-page`.  Hopefully this is enough info to clarify my broader question.

I'm using `SSR` and `getServerSideProps`, and I want to be able to have the same sort of URL structure, with each individual dealer having it's own pages with the specific url path, but they don't need to have their own page content. It all shares the same stuff. I have a page in Prismic called `/interior-doors`. With Next is there a way to allow that `/interior-doors` page to be accessed from `mysite.com/interior-doors` as well as `mysite.com/sacramento-ca/interior-doors` without needing to have 2 separate pages?

Thanks in advance, I can add as much code or as many details as necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually should be able to accomplish this with [dynamic routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes). For your use case of having multiple depths of the URL structure use the same document, [optional catch-all routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#optional-catch-all-routes) might make the most sense. You can then pass whatever you need in as the query and then pass that through to the content, for instance:

```
interior-doors/[[...slug]].js
```

Would match: `/interior-doors, /interior-doors/sacramento-ca, /post/sacramento-ca/interior-doors`

And then you can access the query and use those parameters in your content if you want, so you could actually pull the city name and use it in a headline or copy.

Comment: This is essentially what I ended up doing, and it worked out perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Next.js rewries](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) for these sort of aliases.

There is probably more to your content strategy than I can read out from the intial description but generally speaking duplicate content across 600 pages doesn't sound like you are doing the internet a favour and search engine crawlers might get it at some point too.

Comment: Thank you. Doesn't sound like exactly what I'm needing, but you're on the right track I think. How could my content strategy improve moving forward to make this simpler?

Comment: I don't see myself too competent in SEO and content strategy and one would need to get to know your detailed use case. The rule of thumb is that content duplication is bad; perhaps something like `<link>` tag with `canonical` could help your or consider diversifying the content in first place.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Next's redirects: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects

You can specify, including for dynamic routes, which routes should be 'redirected' to where, like so:

```
module.exports = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:dealer/:product',
        destination: '/:product'
        permanent: false,
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This results in visits to /sacramento-ca/interior-doors to redirect to /interior-doors, etc. This may not fit your exact use case so please check out the documentation for more details.